# Should site specific badge icons show on all accounts?

Tags: discussion, design

When viewing an individuals profile on an SE network site, the accounts page shows badges with that site's theme. The resulting site specific badge icons strike me as odd when paired with other sites. See for example how I have fish badges on the Unix & Linux site:

[image: Fish badges on Unix site?]

Perhaps this account listing page should show either a generic dot icon or use the site specific icons for each site?

Comment: That would probably be rather complicated to implement, as the badges are in one big sprite which doesn't include the generic badge icons.

Comment: @MadScientist That's why I suggested that perhaps the thing to do was make the accounts list use generic dots across the board and forgo the theme entirely. That might look better than site specific icons in a list anyway as they were not meant to match each other so much as their specific site themes.

Comment: The generic dots are in the beta theme, the sprites for this site don't contain them so this is still not easily possible, as far as I can see.

Comment: @MadScientist: They could use the dots from the Trio site themes or just add another item to the sprite for this purpose. This isn't a hard problem to solve technically.

Comment: This would probably be better asked on Meta Stack Overflow, as it pertains to the entire network

Comment: It would even be possible to use a bullet *character* like `&#9679;` and not a graphic at all, so it's not theme-dependent. That does require it to be present in the font file, though.